# How can I batch convert .doc files into .txt so I can import into Excel

Tags: vba, powershell, ms-word

I need to transfer data from a number of Word (mostly .doc, some .docx) files into Excel for better documentation & analysis.
Currently the only way I see to do this is: manually open each file > Save As > plain text > Windows (default). This is arduous and not a good use of time as I have hundreds of documents to do this for.

I am an absolute novice with VBA and Macros, but imagine I can automate most of the work with these.
Alternatively, would PowerShell be able to do this?

I tried following [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48559646/converting-multiple-ms-word-documents-into-txt-files-few-extra-bits?answertab=votes&newreg=d6ca035bfab94028aee647cc83bccc47) to batch convert Word to .txt but when I opened the .txt files they were all blank. If i follow the manual one-by-one SaveAs route, then they have the data saved as text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the code you were using didn't work for you it suggests that the documents you have don't contain form fields. To simply save the documents as text all you need to do is omit the `SaveFormsData:=True`, as below.

```
Sub SaveAllFormData(path As String)
    Dim doc As Document
    Dim fileName As String

    fileName = Dir(path & "*.doc*")

     ' Loop through all .doc files in that path
    Do While fileName <> ""
        Set doc = Application.Documents.Open(path & fileName)

         ' Save form data
        doc.SaveAs2 doc.FullName & ".txt", WdSaveFormat.wdFormatText

        doc.Close wdDoNotSaveChanges
        fileName = Dir
    Loop
End Sub
```